# How can I use my same JavaScript code on a newly loaded page (from a redirect)

Tags: javascript, redirect, scroll

I am basically trying to emulate user experience on multiple websites, so I want a single script that will redirect to a new website, start scrolling to the bottom, and then go back to the original site.  Here is my code, it loads the page just fine but does not scroll.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Benchmark</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadUrl(newLocation)
{
  window.location = newLocation;
  window.onload=pageScroll;
}


function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
        scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void" onclick="loadUrl('anysite.com'); return false;">link-1</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have not gotten to the redirect back page, but that doesn't really matter yet.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you control both pages or are you trying to do this with an external domain?

Comment: External domain, sorry I should have specified.

Comment: If you had influence with the external domain, you might see if they have a Javascript API that you could perhaps pass a GET variable and they could trigger the scroll. But, per your question, it's not possible to maintain the same javascript process while changing pages.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems that will prevent this from working:

1. When you set the window location to a new URL (regardless of it being external or not), the JavaScript on the current page stops executing. It won't have access to the new page as it's been completely replaced (it's unloaded). So, that means your "window.onload" code will never get called. The new page is now active.
2. If you tried an iframe approach and loaded the external page into the iframe, that too will not work as your code cannot access the internal web page (and the scrollBy function) if the web site is from a different domain. You might read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for some more information about this security feature. If your external page is from a web server: www.example.com, and the internal content is from www.microsoft.com, the scripts (and your scrolling code) in www.example.com will not be able to scroll the document.

There are a number of freely available scripting/automation tools that can provide a better and 100% reliable simulation of a user. One for example is from [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/free-testing-framework.aspx). You might want to look at those depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough response!